# Typescript import with sending variable to imported files

Tags: javascript, typescript

Didn't found it in documentation. The question is is there anything in typescript like.

file1.js

```
module.exports = (service) =>
{
   service.doSomeCoolStuff();
}
```

file2.js

```
const file2 = require('./file2')(service)
```

I need to send service object to another file  and work with it. So is there something like this in typescript? I need to uses exactly this construction. I know it is possible to it with class, but requirement is to use it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TypeScript has modules which support ES imports and exports.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

## file1.ts

```
export default (service) => service.doSomeCoolStuff();
```

## file2.ts

```
import doCoolStuffWithService from './file1';
const file2 = doCoolStuffWithService(service);
```